# How to get createdAt and lastModified fields with proper behavior using Kotlin's Exposed ORM?

Tags: sql, kotlin, orm, kotlin-exposed

```
data class User(
    var name: String? = null,
    val mobile: String,
    var email: String? = null
) : Principal, BaseTable()
```

Ideally, what I would want is to have the common logic for the generation of the lastModified, createdAt fields to reside in some common class (e.g: BaseTable)

```
abstract class BaseTable {
    private lateinit var createdAt: DateTime
    private lateinit var lastModified: DateTime
}
```

Which would act as the parent of all my models since I want the createdAt and lastModified fields in every table.

To be clear, here is the behavior I want:

- createdAt: Just store the time when the row was created, and never change again
- lastModified: Every time a row is updated, update this field as well. When a new row is created createdAt = lastModified.

Is there a way to do this using Kotlin (Jetbrains) Exposed SQL library?

Comment: You could define StatementInterceptor which will actualize your fields or just use built in expressions of your database (like `ON UPDATE current_timestamp` in MySQL)

Comment: Could you link to a sample implementation @Tapac?

Answer (score 2):

For `createdAt` case there's `defaultExpression` function:

```
abstract class BaseTable : IntIdTable() {
   val createdAt = datetime("created_at").defaultExpression(CurrentDateTime)
}
```

Where `CurrentDateTime` equals to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` SQL expression

Not aware of any solution for `lastModified`, though. I'm setting it in the DAO manually.

Comment: For `createdAt` there's also `defaultExpression`, at least in current version:
`val createdAt = timestamp("created_at").defaultExpression( CurrentTimestamp() )`.
However, I'm still searching for an automatic solution for `lastModified`.

Answer (score 2):

Spent a day searching for a solution

Here is a possible [recipe](https://github.com/paulkagiri/ExposedDatesAutoFill/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/app/Models.kt)

I myself removed all the abstractions and implemented hooks where I needed them.